# Django - how can i call a model as a string?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a DRF api endpoint that should render some json data from my database. In my view, the name of the model to query to render the data is not fixed, it depends on what query does the user perform.

So i have this:

```
collection = 'MY_MODEL'
queryset = collection.objects.filter(**filters)
```

But this will give the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

This will work instead: `queryset = MY_MODEL.objects.filter(**filters)`

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django actually has a method to do this:

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
ModelClass = import_string('yourapp.models.YOUR_MODEL')
queryset = ModelClass.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Note that you have to provide the full path of your model.

The docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.module_loading.import_string

If you only have a few models you need to support however I would actually advise to just use a dictionary that you maintain yourself:

```
MODEL_MAPPING = {
    "model_a": MyModelAClass,
    "model_b": MyModelBClass,
}
user_input = "model_b"

ModelClass = MODEL_MAPPING.get(user_input)
if ModelClass is not None:
    queryset = ModelClass.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot! This was very helpful. The second method is very clean, but maybe i'll go with the first one since i have a lot of models